# How to merge two identical tables that have a primary key?

Tags: mysql, merge

This seems like a simple task, but I am struggling to find a way to do this. I have two tables (A and B) with the same structure. Both have an auto-increment primary key. I want the data from table B to go in to table A. I tried:

```
insert into A select * from B
```

However I get an error that a primary key already exists. I would like the new rows from table B to get a new primary key when I insert them in to table A - so basically discard the primary key from B but insert all the other columns. Seems like it should be a simple query but I can't figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: `insert into A (col1, col2, col3) values (select col1, col2, col3 from B)`. ignore primary key/auto increment column in insert and select.

Comment: I tried that before and I get this error
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select col1,col2,col3 from B)' at line 1 */

Comment: That is because `INSERT...SELECT` does not use a values list, and `INSERT... VALUES` generally doesn't use `SELECT`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're also selecting (and inserting) the auto_increment id, which fails if such id already exists. To let mysql automatically assign id just select and insert all values besides the id:

```
INSERT INTO A (foo, bar, baz)
SELECT foo, bar, baz FROM B
```

Comment: Works, was a syntax issue, `insert into A (col1,col2,col3) values (select col1,col2,col3 from B)` throws an error. Removed the parenthesis and values works `insert into A (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from B`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the columns you are want to insert from table B to table A, since you want to create a new id you can use a query as follow assuming column1 is they key that we don't want to insert.

```
insert into A (column2, column3) select column2, column3 from B
```

You can also lookup at this [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/11/mysql-insert-command/) that has some good query examples.